# React Hooks: Is more performant to use `useRef` over `useState` to keep track of the boolean toggle state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

**Overview**

I'm implementing a `useToggle` react hook and I want to know if it is more performant to use `useRef` over `useState` to keep track of the boolean toggle state. Since `useRef` doesn't cause re-renders, this should be more efficient right?

**useToggle (Using `useRef`)**

```
const useToggle = () => {
    const stateRef = useRef<boolean>(false);
    
    const toggle = useCallback(() => stateRef.current = !stateRef.current, []);
    
    return [stateRef, toggle];
}
```

**useToggle (Using `useState`)**

```
const useToggle = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<boolean>(false);
    
    const toggle: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<boolean>> = useCallback(() => setState(state => !state), []);
    
    return [state, toggle];
}
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that the difference in performance will be insignificant unless there is an enormous component tree underneath the toggle, or it's being toggled a thousand times per second.

Comment: The question really has nothing to do with performance and everything to do with whether you want to expose a reactive variable or not.

Comment: Which is more performant depends ***entirely*** on the use case. Obviously they don't do the same thing and won't be used to solve the same problems, so which is more performant is an apples to oranges comparison.

Answer (score 1):

I think, its fine to use `useRef` until you don't want any re-renders i.e. any UI changes.

But I do agree to what @Mario said.
Though, you can prevent re-renders using `useRef` but it doesn't mean you should use `useRef` instead of `useState`.

**You should try to minimize the use of states**.

Here you haven't mentioned what `useToggle` is for; thats y its hard to say whether you should use it or not.

And we generally don't compare them as none of then can replace each other; both of them are made for different use cases.

This [blog](https://dev.to/salehmubashar/useref-or-usestate-which-is-better-258j) will give you an idea of when to use what.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the performance but, to be honest, my approach would be the useState one. The reason behind it is simply the one you gave: It causes updates.

What is the point on creating a useToggle hook that returns the state of the toggle if you do not want to use it to update something?